# How to upload a binary file in IE8 then send it to server using xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, xmlhttprequest, input-type-file

I'm working on the web pages of an embeded device. To exchange data between the web page and the application of this device I use xmlhttprequest.

Now I search a way to allow the client to upload a binary (to update the firmware of that device) to the server.

One big limitation : it needs to works in IE8 (a cross browser solution would be ideal, but it's mandatory to work on IE8 first...)

In detail what I have to do :

1. Use the `<input type='file'>` to select the file on the client computer
2. Send the file (using xmlhttprequest?) to the server
3. The server will reassemble the file and to whatever it need to do with it...

I was able to get a binary from the client to the server in chrome, but in IE8, my method was not compatible.

The relevant html file :

```
<input id="uploadFile" type="file" />
```

In the javascript, I tried different way to fire an event with the input file type

```
// does not work in IE8 (get an Obj doesnt support this property or method)
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener("change"),function(e)...
// tried with jQuery, does not work in IE8(I may not using it correctly...)
$('upload').addEvent('change', function(e)....
$('upload').change(function(e)....
```

So my first problem is : how to do a onChange event with the input type file in IE8?

Also the method I was using in chrome (found on this page : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/ ) but that is not working on IE8 :

```
function upload(blobOrFile) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };
  xhr.send(blobOrFile);
}

document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var blob = this.files[0];

  const BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunk sizes.
  const SIZE = blob.size;

  var start = 0;
  var end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;

  while(start < SIZE) {
     upload(blob.slice(start, end));

    start = end;
    end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
  }
}, false);

})();
```

Because the document.querySelector generate an error in IE8, I don't know if the rest of this code works in IE8 (I wish it can works!)

Any help and suggestion will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: You cannot do an ajax file upload with IE8 but I'm sure you can fake it with something like [AjaxFileUpload](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/).

Comment: I will check for the AjaxFileUpload...